# How to make PHP execute Python3 script as root?

Tags: php, python-3.x, scripting, root

I want PHP to execute a Python3 script.
I have done

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('pathtofile.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

But whenever the script is run, I get an error `:Permission Denied`.

I'm running a web server (Apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04) and the VPS has only one user- root.

I have also done`chmod +x path.py` and added the shebang line in the scipt.

Basically, the script is run when a user successfully registers.

Answer (score 0):

You must to add apache user in sudoers file like:
www-data   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
then you can execute script like this: 
'sudo pathtofile.py'

Or you can use compiled wrapper.
Write C program, that executes script, than compile it. Than set sticky bit:
chown root:root wrapper
chmod a+rs wrapper

Than include www-data in the root group.
Now can execute wrapper from your php script, and wrapper will execute python script as root.

Comment: where do I have to add the above?

Comment: sudo echo 'www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >>/etc/sudoers
than execute as "sudo pathtofile.py"